# Get users by most recent order made in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am using **WooCommerce** for my ecommerce site.I am trying to **sort users by recent order** made by their account. Is there any method for doing this? like passing parameters on `get_users()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this custom light SQL query embedded in a function which will return an array of customers IDs sorted by most recent orders date *(for orders status "completed" and "processing")*:

```
function get_users_by_orders_date(){
    global $wpdb;

    // Getting all User IDs by more recent orders
    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
        AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        ORDER BY p.post_date
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Usage in your code:**
>
> ```
> $user_ids = get_users_by_orders_date(); // Array of user IDs
> ```